# Chinese contingency plans for N. Korea collapsing

Tags: china, north-korea

There have been numerous predictions that a collapse in North Korea is imminent. (A recent [example](http://www.dw.com/en/is-north-korea-finally-close-to-collapse/a-19183141))

From what I've read, China would prefer a quiet regime change but given the alternative (total collapse, humanitarian crises, etc) the status quo is preferred. This seems to be reflected by their actions in the UN.

While these represent what are the public and well circulated - albeit vague - plans to prevent a N.Korean collapse, is anyone aware of anything that contains any details on what would happen if they actually collapsed? I'm more interested in what China would do given a previous [question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/7641/what-if-known-are-south-koreas-contingency-plans-if-the-north-korea-regime-su) that addresses, in part, S.Korea's and the United States' plans.

Comment: This question seems to be very speculative. Questions which involve lots of guessing and assumptions are not a good fit for this website.

Comment: While I think it could be answerable if their plans were leaked or if for some reason they announced it, it probably won't be answerable.

Answer (score 5):

Supposedly in 2014, Japan was leaked documents that reportedly showed [China's plans should the nation of North Korea collapse](https://time.com/90617/china-north-korea-plan/). The origin of these documents are yet to be verified, but if they are, there would be [two parts to the plan](https://www.vox.com/2014/5/6/5686858/chinas-secret-plan-for-north-koreas-collapse-revealed):

1. Set up refugee camps on the Chinese side of the border to support millions of fleeing North Koreans
2. Detain North Korean leadership in special camps to be monitored (physical health, mental health, etc.)

This plan would go into effect, but not include China using military might to prop up North Korea or moving into North Korea territory to protect the border. This is because China doesn't seem to want to enter with any kind of potential war with the United States or South Korea that could happen if either party decided to take advantage of North Korea's collapse to reunify Korea. China's policy on that front appears to be: ['No war, no instability, no nukes'.](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2013/02/12/why-china-still-supports-north-korea-in-six-little-words/?arc404=true)